# Good book on Statics and Dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, statics

Could you please suggest a good book on statics and dynamics. The portions I have to cover include

Statics : Equilibrium in 2&3 dimensions, Virtual work,Common catenary etc

Dynamics : Rectilinear motion,SHM,Work and energy,Work and energy,Central orbits

Comment: Theory or questions? Highschool/Olympiads?

Comment: Questions for UPSC prep